# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' plugins.js:1 and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' active.js:1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

my project website shows up like this after I put `id_training` into it.

[image]

I want to show the detail of each training. if remove the `id_training` from the code, the js can work. what should I do?
this is the code from the view:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Welcome/detail/<?= $t['id_training'];?>">
```

this is js that I use in the footer :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper js -->
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- All Plugins js -->
    <script src="assets/siswa/js/plugins/plugins.js"></script>
    <!-- Active js -->
    <script src="assets/siswa/js/active.js"></script>
```

this is the code for plugins.js (not all of it):

```
(function () {
            var method;
            var noop = function noop() {};
            var methods = [
                'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
                'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
                'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
                'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
            ];
            var length = methods.length;
            var console = (window.console = window.console || {});
            while (length--) {
                method = methods[length];
                // Only stub undefined methods.
                if (!console[method]) {
                    console[method] = noop;
                }
            }
        }());
    (function(e){"use strict";e.fn.counterUp=function(t){var n=e.extend({time:400,delay:10},t);return this.each(function(){var t=e(this),r=n,i=function(){var e=[],n=r.time/r.delay,i=t.text(),s=/[0-9]+,[0-9]+/.test(i);i=i.replace(/,/g,"");var o=/^[0-9]+$/.test(i),u=/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/.test(i),a=u?(i.split(".")[1]||[]).length:0;for(var f=n;f>=1;f--){var l=parseInt(i/n*f);u&&(l=parseFloat(i/n*f).toFixed(a));if(s)while(/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(l.toString()))l=l.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/,"$1,$2");e.unshift(l)}t.data("counterup-nums",e);t.text("0");var c=function(){t.text(t.data("counterup-nums").shift());if(t.data("counterup-nums").length)setTimeout(t.data("counterup-func"),r.delay);else{delete t.data("counterup-nums");t.data("counterup-nums",null);t.data("counterup-func",null)}};t.data("counterup-func",c);setTimeout(t.data("counterup-func"),r.delay)};t.waypoint(i,{offset:"100%",triggerOnce:!0})})}})(jQuery);
jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing,jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing,{def:"easeOutQuad",swing:function(n,e,t,r,u){return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](n,e,t,r,u)},easeInQuad:function(n,e,t,r,u){return r*(e/=u)*e+t},easeOutQuad:function(n,e,t,r,u){return-r*(e/=u)*(e-2)+t},easeInOutQuad:function(n,e,t,r,u){return(e/=u/2)<1?r/2*e*e+t:-r/2*(--e*(e-2)-1)+t},easeInCubic:function(n,e,t,r,u){return r*(e/=u)*e*e+t},easeOutCubic:function(n,e,t,r,u){return r*((e=e/u-1)*e*e+1)+t},easeInOutCubic:function(n,e,t,r,u){return(e/=u/2)<1?r/2*e*e*e+t:r/2*((e-=2)*e*e+2)+t},easeInQuart:function(n,e,t,r,u){return r*(e/=u)*e*e*e+t},easeOutQuart:function(n,e,t,r,u){return-r*((e=e/u-1)*e*e*e-1)+t},easeInOutQuart:function(n,e,t,r,u){return(e/=u/2)<1?r/2*e*e*e*e+t:-r/2*((e-=2)*e*e*e-2)+t},easeInQuint:function(n,e,t,r,u){return r*(e/=u)*e*e*e*e+t},easeOutQuint:function(n,e,t,r,u){return r*((e=e/u-1)*e*e*e*e+1)+t},easeInOutQuint:function(n,e,t,r,u){return(e/=u/2)<1?r/2*e*e*e*e*e+t:r/2*((e-=2)*e*e*e*e+2)+t},easeInSine:function(n,e,t,r,u){return-r*Math.cos(e/u*(Math.PI/2))+r+t},easeOutSine:function(n,e,t,r,u){return r*Math.sin(e/u*(Math.PI/2))+t},easeInOutSine:function(n,e,t,r,u){return-r/2*(Math.cos(Math.PI*e/u)-1)+t},easeInExpo:function(n,e,t,r,u){return 0==e?t:r*Math.pow(2,10*(e/u-1))+t},easeOutExpo:function(n,e,t,r,u){return e==u?t+r:r*(-Math.pow(2,-10*e/u)+1)+t},easeInOutExpo:function(n,e,t,r,u){return 0==e?t:e==u?t+r:(e/=u/2)<1?r/2*Math.pow(2,10*(e-1))+t:r/2*(-Math.pow(2,-10*--e)+2)+t},easeInCirc:function(n,e,t,r,u){return-r*(Math.sqrt(1-(e/=u)*e)-1)+t},easeOutCirc:function(n,e,t,r,u){return r*Math.sqrt(1-(e=e/u-1)*e)+t},easeInOutCirc:function(n,e,t,r,u){return(e/=u/2)<1?-r/2*(Math.sqrt(1-e*e)-1)+t:r/2*(Math.sqrt(1-(e-=2)*e)+1)+t},easeInElastic:function(n,e,t,r,u){var a=1.70158,i=0,s=r;if(0==e)return t;if(1==(e/=u))return t+r;if(i||(i=.3*u),s<Math.abs(r)){s=r;var a=i/4}else var a=i/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(r/s);return-(s*Math.pow(2,10*(e-=1))*Math.sin((e*u-a)*(2*Math.PI)/i))+t},easeOutElastic:function(n,e,t,r,u){var a=1.70158,i=0,s=r;if(0==e)return t;if(1==(e/=u))return t+r;if(i||(i=.3*u),s<Math.abs(r)){s=r;var a=i/4}else var a=i/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(r/s);return s*Math.pow(2,-10*e)*Math.sin((e*u-a)*(2*Math.PI)/i)+r+t},easeInOutElastic:function(n,e,t,r,u){var a=1.70158,i=0,s=r;if(0==e)return t;if(2==(e/=u/2))return t+r;if(i||(i=u*(.3*1.5)),s<Math.abs(r)){s=r;var a=i/4}else var a=i/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(r/s);return 1>e?-.5*(s*Math.pow(2,10*(e-=1))*Math.sin((e*u-a)*(2*Math.PI)/i))+t:s*Math.pow(2,-10*(e-=1))*Math.sin((e*u-a)*(2*Math.PI)/i)*.5+r+t},easeInBack:function(n,e,t,r,u,a){return void 0==a&&(a=1.70158),r*(e/=u)*e*((a+1)*e-a)+t},easeOutBack:function(n,e,t,r,u,a){return void 0==a&&(a=1.70158),r*((e=e/u-1)*e*((a+1)*e+a)+1)+t},easeInOutBack:function(n,e,t,r,u,a){return void 0==a&&(a=1.70158),(e/=u/2)<1?r/2*(e*e*(((a*=1.525)+1)*e-a))+t:r/2*((e-=2)*e*(((a*=1.525)+1)*e+a)+2)+t},easeInBounce:function(n,e,t,r,u){return r-jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(n,u-e,0,r,u)+t},easeOutBounce:function(n,e,t,r,u){return(e/=u)<1/2.75?r*(7.5625*e*e)+t:2/2.75>e?r*(7.5625*(e-=1.5/2.75)*e+.75)+t:2.5/2.75>e?r*(7.5625*(e-=2.25/2.75)*e+.9375)+t:r*(7.5625*(e-=2.625/2.75)*e+.984375)+t},easeInOutBounce:function(n,e,t,r,u){return u/2>e?.5*jQuery.easing.easeInBounce(n,2*e,0,r,u)+t:.5*jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(n,2*e-u,0,r,u)+.5*r+t}});
```

this is active.js code :

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var browserWindow = $(window);

    // :: 1.0 Preloader Active Code
    browserWindow.on('load', function () {
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    // :: 2.0 Countdown Active Code
    $('[data-countdown]').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
        $this.countdown(finalDate, function (event) {
            $this.html(event.strftime('<div>%D <span>Days</span></div> <div>%H <span>Hours</span></div> <div>%M <span>Minutes</span></div> <div>%S <span>Seconds</span></div>'));
        });
    });

    // :: 3.0 Nav Active Code
    if ($.fn.classyNav) {
        $('#cleverNav').classyNav();
    }

    // :: 4.0 Sliders Active Code
    if ($.fn.owlCarousel) {
        var tutors = $('.tutors-slide');
        tutors.owlCarousel({
            items: 3,
            margin: 0,
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
            dots: false,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 6000,
            smartSpeed: 1000,
            center: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                },
                576: {
                    items: 2
                },
                992: {
                    items: 3
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // :: 5.0 Gallery Active Code
    if ($.fn.magnificPopup) {
        $('.video-btn').magnificPopup({
            type: 'iframe'
        });
    }

    // :: 6.0 ScrollUp Active Code
    if ($.fn.scrollUp) {
        browserWindow.scrollUp({
            scrollSpeed: 1500,
            scrollText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>'
        });
    }

    // :: 7.0 CouterUp Active Code
    if ($.fn.counterUp) {
        $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 2000
        });
    }

    // :: 8.0 Sticky Active Code
    if ($.fn.sticky) {
        $(".clever-main-menu").sticky({
            topSpacing: 0
        });
    }

    // :: 9.0 wow Active Code
    if (browserWindow.width() > 767) {
        new WOW().init();
    }

    // :: 10.0 prevent default a click
    $('a[href="#"]').click(function ($) {
        $.preventDefault()
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you include the *rendered* HTML?  What you have in your model/controller etc doesn't matter

Comment: this the first line of the plugins.js : // Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function () {
    var method;
    var noop = function noop() {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];

Comment: And the rendered link?

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't know how to show you the rendered HTML :((

Comment: what is rendered link?

Comment: Does `$t['id_training']` contain any `"` ?

Comment: @Dum no it's not

Comment: Open the page in the browser and view-source (then locate the relevant link) - or open the page in the browser, press F12 (chrome) and use the elements tab to find your link (or the selector to select it with the mouse) - or open the page in the browser, right click on the link and choose inspect.  Then copy the html for the link

Comment: @freedomn-m this?  <a href="http://localhost/training/Welcome/detail/TRN0001"><h4> Adobe Photoshop </h4></a>

Comment: Do you have any `<?php` tags in your .js files?

Comment: @freedomn-m no, I upload the code in my question...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really tel us what is in active.js or plugins.js So it hard to tell exactly.

It looks like you have some php in those files and your webserver is not letting PHP parse it. Usually a webserver is not setup to let PHP handle .js files as they are usually static files and passing them through PHP is really expensive compared to just out them to the browser. You can check this by opening the files in browser and see if they have PHP code in them, if they then PHP is not parsing the file.

You can configure your server to let PHP take care of .js files or better yet renaming to .php.js so .js without PHP don't have to be parsed. My approach is usually to get all the data js need from a PHP endpoint or just added it the HTML in a script section.

Hope it helps